# How to rewrite urls (.htaccess) with nginx in ubuntu 14.04 server?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm having some trouble performing this in nginx. I find no .htaccess file and I'm in doubt whether I actually need to install some extra library to convert from apache to nginx mechanics or if I can do url rewrite another way. Can someone point me towards the right direction? Thank you very much!

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/rewrite

Comment: @AlexeyTen +1 for the url shortening trick, wasn't aware the nginx docs had that.

Comment: @AlexeyTen which is the file I should work with?